# Truncating Poisson distribution on desired support in Matlab

Tags: matlab, distribution, poisson

I want to construct a 3-dimensional Poisson distribution in Matlab with lambda parameters `[0.4, 0.2, 0.6]` and I want to truncate it to have support in `[0;1;2;3;4;5]`. The 3 components are independent.

This is what I do

```
clear
n=3; %number components of the distribution 

supp_marginal=0:1:5;
suppsize_marginal=size(supp_marginal,2); 

supp_temp=repmat(supp_marginal.',1,n); 
supp_temp_cell=num2cell(supp_temp,1); 
output_temp_cell=cell(1,n);
[output_temp_cell{:}] = ndgrid(supp_temp_cell{:});
supp=zeros(suppsize_marginal^n,n);

for h=1:n
    temp=output_temp_cell{h};
    supp(:,h)=temp(:);  
end
suppsize=size(supp,1); 

lambda_1=0.4;
lambda_2=0.2;
lambda_3=0.6;

pr_mass=zeros(suppsize,1);
for j=1:suppsize
    pr_mass(j)=(poisspdf(supp(j,1),lambda_1).*...
                poisspdf(supp(j,2),lambda_2).*...
                poisspdf(supp(j,3),lambda_3))/...
                sum(poisspdf(supp(:,1),lambda_1).*...
                    poisspdf(supp(:,2),lambda_2).*...
                    poisspdf(supp(j,3),lambda_3));
end
```

When I compute the mean of the obtained distribution, I get `lambda_1` and `lambda_2` but not `lambda_3`.

```
lambda_empirical=sum(supp.*repmat(pr_mass,1,3));
```

Question: why I do not get `lambda_3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:   Truncation changes the distribution so different means are expected.**

---

This is expected as [truncation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution) itself has **changed the distribution** and certainly adjusts the mean. You can see this from the experiment below. Notice that for your chosen parameters, this just starts to become noticable around *lambda* = 0.6.

Similar to [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution), this illustrates the difference between E[*X*] (expectation of *X* without truncation; fancy word for mean) and E[ *X* | *LB* ≤ *X* ≤ *UB*] (expectation of *X* given it is on interval [*LB*,*UB*]). This conditional expectation implies a different distribution than the unconditional distribution of *X*  (~Poisson(*lambda*)).

[image: Plot showing gap in mean due to truncation effect]

```
% MATLAB R2018b
% Setup
LB = 0;   % lowerbound 
UB = 5;   % upperbound

% Simple test to compare theoretical means with and without truncation
TestLam = 0.2:0.01:1.5;
Gap = zeros(size(TestLam(:)));
for jj = 1:length(TestLam)
    TrueMean = mean(makedist('Poisson','Lambda',TestLam(jj)));
    TruncatedMean = mean(truncate(makedist('Poisson','Lambda',TestLam(jj)),LB,UB));
    Gap(jj) = TrueMean-TruncatedMean;
end

plot(TestLam,Gap)
```

Notice the gap with these truncation bounds and a lambda of 0.6 is still small and is negligible as lambda approaches zero.

```
lam = 0.6;    %  <---- try different values   (must be greater than 0)
pd = makedist('Poisson','Lambda',lam)
pdt = truncate(pd,LB,UB)
mean(pd)                         % 0.6
mean(pdt)                        % 0.5998
```

---

Other Resources:
1. Wiki for [Truncated Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution)
2. [What is a Truncated Distribution](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/truncated-normal-distribution/)
3. MATLAB documentation for [`truncate()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.truncate.html), [`makedist()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/makedist.html)
4. MATLAB: [Working with Probability Distribution (Objects)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/working-with-probability-distributions.html)